# Why it can get in the For loop?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, for-loop

`array` has 0 objects, so `array.count` is 0, and then `(array.count - 1)` is `-1`, `i < -1` is `-1`, why it can get in this for loop?

```
for (int i=0; i<array.count-1; i++) {
    NSLog(@"why it can get in this for loop?");

    for (int j=0; j<array.count-i-1; j++) {          
        NSLog(@"why it can get in this for loop?");     
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you just undo all of the edit that have been made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSArray count` has a type of `NSUInteger`. That's an unsigned integer.

So when you do `array.count - 1` and `array.count` is `0`, the result is not `-1`, it's a really big number (either 2^32 - 1 or 2^64 - 1). This is a result of working with unsigned values.

You can make your loop work as expected by avoiding the unsigned math. Use:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < (NSInteger)array.count - 1; i++)
```

BTW - you can see the problem more clearly if you do this:

```
int cnt = array.count - 1; // Look at this value in the debugger, it's not -1
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, use fast enumeration.  ;)

Comment: @nhgrif How? The inner loop depends on the index of the outer loop.

Comment: Outer loop could easily use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`.  Inner loop *could* do the same by setting the `stop` parameter at the correct index.

Comment: @nhgrif OK, when you said "fast enumeration" I was thinking of `for (x in foo)`.

Comment: @rmaddy  int cnt = array.count - 1; // Look at this value in the debugger, it's not -1
 How can I see the result ?Xcode game me tips - " Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int'"

Comment: Change `int` to `NSInteger`. That code is only so you can see problem. That code is not meant to fix your problem. The first part of my answer is a solution.